# What's the 日本語 equivalent of "Wipe them off the map"?

Tags: meaning, set-phrases, phrases, phrase-requests

皆さん、こんばんは！

What is the 日本語 equivalent of saying the semi-set-phrase(or whatever you call set-phrases with parts you can fill in) "Wipe them off the map"?

Like when you say "North Korea knows that if they threaten the economy of Japan, the USA wouldn't be above just wiping them off the map".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an exact word for this in Japanese, "地図から消し去る" which is actually a direct translation of "Wipe them off the map" but quite common.

> アメリカが本気になれば北朝鮮を地図から消し去るのに10日とかからないだろう。

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it depends on how you go around doing it.
But a term that I fancy and seems to fit well in this situation would be

> [全滅]{ぜんめつ}させる

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think it's not used commonly and I'd say 消し去る.

Comment: 「全滅させる」ならぴったりだと思います。 `wipe ... off the map 全滅させる, [一掃]{いっそう}する` ([ランダムハウス英和大辞典](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/ej/785106/meaning/m0u/)) / `wipe … off the map 全滅させる, 消し去る` ([Weblio英和](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/wipe+off+the+map)]) / `wipe ... off the map …を全滅させる` (プログレッシブ英和中辞典) / `wipe a fort off the map 砦を全滅させる` (ジーニアス英和辞典)